# what is the use of "of_match_ptr()" in device drivers

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, device, device-tree

During my work in device drivers, I came to know that `of_match_table()` is to point the tuple of compatibility strings.

However, I couldn't find the importance of `of_match_ptr()`.

Comment: It’s not important. I might give an answer to this later, but in 99% cases it’s not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`of_match_ptr()` is a preprocessor macro defined in [include/linux/of.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/of.h):

```
#ifdef CONFIG_OF
#define of_match_ptr(_ptr)    (_ptr)
#else /* CONFIG_OF */
#define of_match_ptr(_ptr)    NULL
#endif /* CONFIG_OF */
```

When the kernel is compiled with Device Tree and Open Firmware support, i.e. `CONFIG_OF=y` it will result in the passed pointer. Otherwise it will yield NULL.

Using the macro instead of directly passing the pointer, is to guard the `of_match_table` member. There are bus drivers which check `of_match_table` for NULL to not dereference an invalid pointer.

However, many drivers are compiled in-tree with a compile switch defined in their corresponding Kconfig that already depends on `CONFIG_OF`. For example, the compile switch of a driver for analog device ADV748X video decoder [has this dependency](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/media/i2c/Kconfig#n236):

```
config VIDEO_ADV748X
    tristate "Analog Devices ADV748x decoder"
    depends on VIDEO_V4L2 && I2C
    depends on OF
    select MEDIA_CONTROLLER
    select VIDEO_V4L2_SUBDEV_API
    select REGMAP_I2C
    select V4L2_FWNODE
    help
      V4L2 subdevice driver for the Analog Devices
      ADV7481 and ADV7482 HDMI/Analog video decoders.

      To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the
      module will be called adv748x.
```

and omits the macro in [drivers/media/i2c/adv748x/adv748x-core.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/media/i2c/adv748x/adv748x-core.c):

```
static struct i2c_driver adv748x_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "adv748x",
        .of_match_table = adv748x_of_table,
        .pm = &adv748x_pm_ops,
    },
    .probe_new = adv748x_probe,
    .remove = adv748x_remove,
};
```